# Lucidchart - how to delete objects between layers

Tags: layer, lucidchart

I understand about the power of layers for additive operations, ie extending a diagram by showing more options/more detail etc.
However what I want to understand is what is the way in which layers can be used to fundamentally change the objects in the base diagram.
for instance, if I want a business process whereby the connections between entities no long go from A to B to C but go from A to D to E, I want to be able to remove the connectors from the base layer within my FMO layer and add the new connectors acordingly.
Is there a clever way of achieving this using layers and lucidchart?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by having 3 layers: one for the elements that don't change (your "base layer"), one for the connectors (or elements) that you want to hide and finally one layer for the new elements. You can create a button with actions to toggle the second and third layers so that they are not visible at the same time and easily see your model evolution.